# How to sort Rails AR.find by number of objects in a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I write an AR find query to have the results ordered by the number of records in a has_many association?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

I want to do something like...

```
User.find(:all, :order => photos.count)
```

I realize my find is not valid code. Say I have the following data.

```
User 1, which has 3 photos 
User 2, which has 5 photos 
User 3, which has 2 photos
```

I want my find to bring me back the users in the order of...

```
User 2, 
User 1, 
User 3
```

based on the count of of the users photos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't want an extra column, you could always ask for an extra column in the returned result set:

```
User.all(:select => "#{User.table_name}.*, COUNT(#{Photo.table_name}.id) number_of_photos",
         :joins => :photos,
         :order => "number_of_photos")
```

This generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(photos.id) number_of_photos
FROM `users` INNER JOIN `photos` ON photos.user_id = users.id
ORDER BY number_of_photos
```

Comment: This really what I was looking for I just didn't explain it well.

Comment: +1 For using Model.table_name, -1 for not using :joins => "#{Photo.table_name.pluralize}" !

Comment: -1 for eager-loading everything, -1 for writing your own SQL counting that everybody uses MySQL.

Comment: @ChuckE -1 for not realizing the date at which this was posted. -1 for not realizing that COUNT is part of at least SQL99, and that `column alias` is also part of SQL99. -1 for not realizing that the query does not eager-load anything. -1 for a non-constructive comment.

Comment: it does eager-load, it's an .all call. -1 for me for not realizing the date indeed, +1 for raising the issue of having not-anymore up-to-date answers, which is not your problem, but stack overflow's. Can you add an extra whitespace to your answer so I can remove my -1?

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way to achieve this is probably to add a counter cache to that model and then sort by that column.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
end
```

And be sure to add a column to your `users` table called `photos_count`.

Then you will be able to...

```
User.find(:all, :order => 'photos_count')
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to add a counter cache column, your only option is to sort after the find. If you `:include` the association in your find, you won't incur any additional database work.

```
users = User.find(:all, :include => :photos).sort_by { |u| -u.photos.size }
```

Note the negative sign in the `sort_by` block to sort from high to low.

Comment: I believe, retrieving and only then sorting ruby objects is a lot slower then preforming sorting on a DB level.

Comment: Which is faster will depend on the specific situation. On a very busy database server, offloading the sort to the application server (assuming different hardware), might be faster. In this case, you're right because my solution pulls in the Photo records. Avoiding the `:include` and still doing the sort in Ruby would incur additional queries, which is even worse. François's accepted answer shows how to sort within the query, without pulling in the Photos, which is almost certainly the best solution for this case.

Answer (score 5):

I would advise you not to write direct SQL, since implementations of it may vary from store to store. Fortunately, you have arel:

```
User.joins(:photos).group(Photo.arel_table[:user_id]).
     order(Photo.arel_table[:user_id].count)
```

Comment: Why are we not funding this?

Comment: Do you know of a way to add the sort direction as well so it's ascending or descending?

Answer (score 1):

[Counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) will help, but you'll need an extra column in the db.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment on the top answer, but I can't for some reason. According to this post:

http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface

The `User.all(options)` method will be deprecated after Rails 3.0.3, and replaced with a bunch of other (handy, chainable) active record type stuff, but it makes it very hard to figure out how to put together the same kind of query.

As a result, I've gone ahead and implemented the counter cache method. This was pretty easy and painless with the exception that you need to remember to update the column information in your migration, otherwise all existing records will have "0."

Here's what I used in my migration:

```
class AddUserCountToCollections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :collections, :collectionusers_count, :integer, :default => 0
    Collection.reset_column_information
    Collection.all.each do |c| 
      Collection.update_counters c.id, :collectionusers_count => c.collectionusers.count
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :collections, :collectionusers_count
  end
end
```

In theory this should be faster, too. Hope that's helpful going forward.

Answer (score -4):

Your question doesn't make sense. The `:order` parameter specifies a column name and an optional ordering direction i.e. asc(ending) or desc(ending).

What is the result that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Right, I realize my find is not valid code.

Say I have the following data.

User 1, which has 3 photos
User 2, which has 5 photos
User 3, which has 2 photos

I want my find to bring me back the users in the order of...

User 2,
User 1,
User 3

based on the count of of the users photos.

Comment: He's trying to sort users by the sum of their photos