# ActiveRecord ordering based on nested resource size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given I got this query

```
@users = User.all
```

And I also have @users.received_likes.size

How can I order results based on User.received_likes.size ?

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981051/how-to-sort-rails-ar-find-by-number-of-objects-in-a-has-many-relationship

Answer (score 0):

```
@users = User.all.sort_by {|u| u.received_likes.size}
```

Comment: I think the OP would want a fast SQL solution, see the duplicated question.