# How can i make a query that returns the top 10 users with most activities done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I want to create a page view that shows a leaderboard of an user. That user can have many friends and those friends can have many activities. How can I make a query that returns the top 10 users with most activities done?  Example: there are 50 users in the system and i want to see returned "User 1 : 53 activities ";"User 2 : 49 activities " , ... User 10 : 22 activities ".

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :passive_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :active_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :passive_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: true}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :account
  has_many :pending_friends, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend
  has_many :requested_friendships, -> { where(friendships: { approved: false}) }, :through => :passive_friendships, :source => :account

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :activities
  has_many :sports, through: :activities

  GENDER_TYPES = ["Male", "Female"]
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 30}
  validates :gender, presence: true
  validates :year_Of_Birth, presence: true
  validates :month_Of_Birth, presence: true
  validates :day_Of_Birth, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true

def friends
    active_friends | passive_friends
  end



class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Account"

  end



class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sport
  belongs_to :account
  has_one :place

  AMBIENT_TYPES = ["Outdoor", "Indoor"]
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates_numericality_of :duration, :on => :create, presence: true
  validates :year, presence: true
  validates :month, presence: true
  validates :day, presence: true
  validates :resume, length: {maximum: 200}
```

And where should I write the query? In views i created a directory called pages and made a html.erb file called leaderboard inside it. I have a controller named pages. I should make a function in there? like :

```
def leaderboard
"and put the query here right?"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can add a counter to the `Activity` class:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :sport
  belongs_to :account, :counter_cache => true
  has_one :place
  ...
```

then add a column to your `Account` table called `activities_count` where you can then call:

```
Account.find(:all, :order => 'activities_count', :limit => 10)
```

I used this answer to help (there is also another method listed here): [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981051/how-to-sort-rails-ar-find-by-number-of-objects-in-a-has-many-relationship)

Comment: I did what you said but now I'm having the following error: http://tinypic.com/r/14doz8n/8 , what can I do in order to solve it?

Comment: Did you add the activities_count column to your Account table and run the migration?

Comment: What if I wanted to order by  2 parameters? like the user with most activities or the user with most time doing activities?